# SELECT with OR statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I would like to get following data: if :Code is not NULL, i wanna match with all 4 criteria: Code, Contactor, Type and Nomenclature. If :Code is NULL, i wanna match only Contractor, Type and Nomenclature. I wrote some query here

```
SELECT "Nomenclature" as "IdNom",
       "Cod"          as "ContrCode",
       "Contanctor"
FROM "КодНоменклатуры"

WHERE (:Code IS NOT NULL OR "Code" = ANY (:Code :: text[]))

  AND ("Contactor" = :Contractor::integer
  AND "Type" = :IsSupplier::integer
  AND "Nomenclature" IS NOT NULL)
```

But it doesn't work correctly. When i put a Code, it query everything thath match Contractor, Type and Nomenclature but not Code. If i don't put a code, the result is correct, i match Contractor, Type and Nomenclature.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "Nomenclature" AS "IdNom", "Cod" AS "ContrCode", "Contanctor"
FROM "КодНоменклатуры"
WHERE (
        :Code IS NOT NULL AND "Contactor" = :Contractor::integer AND "Type" = IsSupplier::integer AND "Nomenclature" IS NOT NULL
      ) 
      OR 
      (
        "Code" = ANY (:Code :: text[]) AND "Contactor" = :Contractor::integer
      )
```

Comment: it gives the same result even if i put a specific code in Code

Answer (score 0):

`...WHERE :Code IS NOT NULL...` will always evaluate to TRUE as long as you pass something to :Code. Therefore the part after the `OR` won't be evaluated anymore because the whole term is TRUE then.

Given that you pass an array Literal correctly so that the cast to text[] will work the correct Query should be

```sql
SELECT "Nomenclature" as "IdNom",
       "Cod"          as "ContrCode",
       "Contanctor"
FROM "КодНоменклатуры"

WHERE (:Code IS NOT NULL AND "Code" = ANY (:Code :: text[]))

  AND ("Contactor" = :Contractor::integer
  AND "Type" = :IsSupplier::integer
  AND "Nomenclature" IS NOT NULL)
```

mention the line 
WHERE (:Code IS NOT NULL **AND** "Code" = ANY (:Code :: text[]))

Comment: you are right, if i change it to IS NULL and don't put any :Code - the result is NULL

Comment: Keep it in brackets, but replace `...OR..` with an `...AND...` to include the evaluation of the second term which is inside the brackets.

However, I am not sure if the cast to text-array afterwards works, as I couldn't get this working on a table in my own setting.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an tested adaption of your snipped which should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:
WHERE 
  ((:Code IS NULL OR :Code='{}') OR "Code" = ANY (:Code :: text[]))